# Too Many Line Artifacts in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.8

I'm developing an application in WPF and .Net 4.8, and I am having trouble getting rid of some line artifacts. (see gif link below)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xSoj__ON0Wk1AGx4H8hcw6AbsA2qr-ln/view?usp=sharing

I've tried doing "RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = RenderMode.SoftwareOnly" and while it does help with the line artifacts it makes part of the application extremely slow.

I've also tried doing "UseLayoutRounding = True" in most of my XAML elements and it does not seem to get any better.

I am hoping I can completely get rid of all line artifacts. I should have looked into this when I first started the project but I thought it would be an easy fix. Now just hoping someone has dealt with this before and found a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try updating your graphic card drivers.

Comment: @MaciekŚwiszczowski I see it across multiple PCs. I just got a new one as a matter of fact. With the Gigabyte NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 1650 graphic card. I also see this on a surface pro, and surface book 2. All have up to date graphics driver it appears.

Comment: Do you use any specific technology that would influence how the window is being rendered? Like Mahapps.Metro? Or any Win32 calls in Window constructor? Did you try to extract the faulty view only and render it in older .NET Framework, or .NET Core? If it's reproducible in .NET Core 3.0 it's more possible someone from Microsoft will support that issue.

Comment: Hello @MaciekŚwiszczowski, I am planning to migrate my app to .Net Core 3 in a couple days. I will see if that fixes the problem. If not I will take your advice and take it to microsoft. Thanks.

Comment: I have migrated my .Net Framework 4.8 application to .Net Core 3 and the problem persists.

Comment: Lol. I've never seen something like that. If you'd be able to make a repro, I'd have time this week to analyze it.

Comment: @MaciekŚwiszczowski yeah it's strange. And no worries for now I have opened a ticket with microsoft (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/798097/too-many-line-artifacts-in-wpf.html) lets hope they can help, thank you.

Comment: Cool! I'd add there the information you provided in your comments, that you see it on multiple machines with modern graphic cards.